# Проблема с нахождением элементов jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5, canvas

Использую canvas как фон для некого `div`. При нажатии на "кнопку" отображаются дополнительные объекты и `canvas`. С помощью jQuery получаю положение этих объектов в пикселях и на canvas рисую линию от объекта до "кнопки". Код работает нормально для самого первого примера, но при нажатии на следующую "кнопку" часть кода игнорируется:

```
target.closest(".contain").find(".servers .object").each(function(){

   ctx.moveTo(pos_x, pos_y_1);
   ctx.lineTo(pos_x, pos_y_2);
   pos_x += width;

});
```

Т.е. он не находит "объекты" и не производит рисовку. Никак не могу понять с чем это связано. Чтобы было более понятно привожу весь код здесь: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgGGoN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема оказалась не в селекторах, а в возвращаемых значениях. Потому как .position возвращает координаты относительно документа. Я же предполагал, что возвращаемое значение происходит относительно родительского элемента. Т.о. я пытался нарисовать линию за пределами canvas и она конечно же не отображалась.

Читайте документацию и не позорьтесь.
Ссылка на документацию: https://api.jquery.com/position/